# Alignment with in a table cell

Tags: php, html, css

http://www.dissension.se/shop/

The second table has some issues with alignment. It seems as if when the data within the cell causes the cell to expand height wise, that it throws everything off. However, if I set the height of the cell to 500px, it just expands the cell, but the images still do not align.

(Currently the height is set to 250, and you can still see that the images do not align)

The code is XHTML 1.0 strict validated.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use tables for layout in XHTML Strict.
Check [Cross-Browser Inline-Block](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) for vetically aligning images.